# Akeneo docker installation Elasticsearch error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-5, akeneo

I have an issue with the installation of the installation of Akeneo v2.3 (with docker)

I have run the installation steps found under:
https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/install_pim/docker/installation_docker.html
until:

`docker-compose exec fpm bin/console --env=prod pim:install --force --symlink --clean`

Where I get the error:

> Reset elasticsearch indexes
>
> In StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php line 51:
>
> No alive nodes found in your cluster
>
> The command terminated with an error code: 1. Error during PIM
>   installation. The command terminated with an error code: 1.

With: `docker-compose exec elasticsearch bash` then `curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'` I can see that the elasticsearch service is running and gives a positive response:

> {   "name" : "PEA3LJM",   "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
>   "cluster_uuid" : "yOqBWRxwShKajvjwyTkf0A",   "version" : {
>       "number" : "5.5.3",
>       "build_hash" : "9305a5e",
>       "build_date" : "2017-09-07T15:56:59.599Z",
>       "build_snapshot" : false,
>       "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"   },   "tagline" : "You Know, for Search" }

What am I doing wrong :( ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might have forgotten to update your `index_hosts` parameter, or made a typo: in `app/config/parameters.yml` be sure to update these values:

```
database_host: mysql
index_hosts: 'elastic:changeme@elasticsearch:9200'
```

(the other default values are OK), then empty your cache and resume installation process, it should run fine ;)